# SF Symbols in Map wont apply colors

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, mapkit, sf-symbols

I am trying to set up a Map with UIKit, using SF Symbols as Annotations. So far so good.

The problem is that the symbols are black, i would like to change the color to white.

```
annotationView.image = UIImage(systemName: "23.circle.fill")!.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
```

doesn't do the job. As a matter of fact, if I use normal Pins, i am able to change the color.

It just doesn't work with SF Symbols.

This is my code

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import UIKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {



    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let myMapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        return myMapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.289912, longitude: 19.764172)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.027, longitudeDelta: 0.027)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        view.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid

        view.delegate = context.coordinator

        let Stand = Staende()
        for x in 1...47 {
            view.addAnnotation(Stand.mitDerNummer(x))

        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator{
         MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }
}



// Just the location of annotations
class Staende {

    var Standname: [Int: [CLLocationDegrees]] = [0: [49.289912, 11.764172],
        1: [49.286350, 11.752594], 2: [49.285030, 11.756457], 3: [49.285660, 11.760449], 4: [49.288375, 11.756384],
        5: [49.282156, 11.756804], 6: [49.282291, 11.759722], 7: [49.283888, 11.763349], 8: [49.296440, 11.769589],
        9: [49.283813, 11.766361], 10: [49.282745, 11.767006], 11: [49.281876, 11.769693], 12: [49.285313, 11.770928],
        13: [48.282069, 11.771333], 14: [49.285064, 11.773408], 15: [49.287436, 11.772958], 16: [49.287954, 11.771348],
        17: [48.289525, 11.772810], 18: [49.290832, 11.771648], 19: [49.283636, 11.773671], 20: [49.292861, 11.773709],
        21: [49.284230, 11.758675], 22: [49.297040, 11.775138], 23: [49.298002, 11.775465], 24: [49.294852, 11.774368],
        25: [49.292690, 11.771520], 26: [49.287850, 11.754731], 27: [49.299254, 11.774461], 28: [49.284187, 11.753743],
        29: [49.294497, 11.766336], 30: [49.293562, 11.766357], 31: [49.292035, 11.765755], 32: [49.294161, 11.763869],
        33: [49.293591, 11.761708], 34: [49.292360, 11.763438], 35: [49.291680, 11.763557], 36: [49.290670, 11.762457],
        37: [49.289053, 11.765481], 38: [49.289864, 11.769767], 39: [49.295175, 11.764827], 40: [49.288745, 11.760020],
        41: [49.288123, 11.760888], 42: [49.288417, 11.762843], 43: [49.287116, 11.762057], 44: [49.286426, 11.757369],
        45: [49.286686, 11.765102], 46: [49.287328, 11.767133], 47: [49.279872, 11.758877], 48: [0, 0],
        49: [0, 0], 50: [0, 0]
    ]

    func mitDerNummer(_ standNummer: Int) -> MKPointAnnotation {
        let Stand = MKPointAnnotation()
        Stand.title = "Stand \(standNummer)"

        let latitude = Standname[standNummer]![0]
        let longitude = Standname[standNummer]![1]
        Stand.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        return Stand
    }

}



class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
      var mapViewController: MapView
      let Stand = Staende()

      init(_ control: MapView) {
          self.mapViewController = control

      }


      func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor
           annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

         //Custom View for Annotation
          let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customView")
          annotationView.canShowCallout = true

          //Your custom image icon
        for (standNummer, _) in Stand.Standname {
            if annotation.title == "Stand \(standNummer)" {

                annotationView.image = UIImage(systemName: "\(standNummer).circle")!.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)

            }
        }


        return annotationView
    } 



}
```

I also tried to changing it via UIImage extension with the following code:

```swift
extension UIImage {

  func colorized(color : UIColor) -> UIImage {

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.setBlendMode(.multiply)
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)
    }

    let colorizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return colorizedImage!

  }
}
```

I would prefer to have them in white color to have a better visualisation of them on the map

Comment: What if you change alwaysTemplate to alwaysOriginal?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me (adjust `size` as desired):

```
let circle = UIImage(systemName:"23.circle.fill")!.withTintColor(.white)
let size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
v.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:size).image {
    _ in circle.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
}
```

Comment: I still think this is a bug, but I'm glad there's an easy workaround.